# How do I subtract 1 from each number in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

If I have

```js
var numberarr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

How would i make it into

```js
var numberarr2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
```

by decrementing 1 from each element?

Answer (score 32):

You can use [`.map( )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var numberarr2 = numberarr.map( function(value) { 
    return value - 1; 
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// Create an array to hold our new values
var numberArr2 = [];

// Iterate through each element in the original array
for(var i = 0; i < numberArr1.length; i++) {

    // Decrement the value of the original array and push it to the new one
    numberArr2.push(numberArr1[i] - 1);
}
```