# Add each value set in an array with a value

Tags: jquery

I want to add a number to each value set in an array list

Suppose array value is [1,2,3,4] and i want to add a value 2 to each value in an array and want a result like [3,4,5,6]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I subtract 1 from each number in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060790/how-do-i-subtract-1-from-each-number-in-an-array)

Comment: I want to add a value here not subtract

Comment: Have you considered trying to use the `+` operator?

Comment: i have tried this  var numberArr2 = [];
for(var i = 0; i < final_value.length; i++) {
    numberArr2.push(final_value[i] + 1);
}
alert(numberArr2);

Comment: but it will concat 1 instead of add

Comment: Then your input is not what you posted in the question - you do not have numbers. Cast to a number before adding instead

Comment: please check my ans

Comment: Ok i got my answaer

Comment: @dipti If you find any answer from below useful, please upvote and mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach` to increment the values in array as

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
arr.forEach((v, i, a) => {
    a[i] = v + 1;
});
console.log(arr);
```

Another way is by using the `map` operator. This will create a ew copy thus is suitable only with less values in array

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
let newArr = arr.map(v => v + 1);
console.log(newArr);
```